# Does curl errno 54 mean the server can't finish sending packets?

Tags: curl, ebay-api

In an attempt to do a GET to this endpoint:

```
https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item|110450293508|0?fieldgroups=COMPACT
```

Where ${authcode} below is an OAuth2 authorization code about 1900 bytes long:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${authcode}"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
curl: (56) LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
```

I'm pretty sure the auth code is valid, since it was just obtained in the previous curl call. Does this seem like it's a problem on the server? eBay's sandbox is notoriously flaky, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I personally have yet to get my sandbox credentials to work, so I run my tests with production keys.  With that being said, are you able to get your `access_token` to work on other calls?  Using the incorrect token is the most common cause for issues with ebay's api, and their error messages can be misleading if not completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much, Caleb. Good suggestion. Unfortunately I don't have API access for this particular call in Production. I have had my auth codes work fine previously.

However when I notified eBay they said they're having trouble with the developer portal, so my guess looks to be right. You can reach me at github.com/tomcam if you want to chat about this stuff.